# How do you style a div in internal css

Tags: html

I don't understand why this is happening
I am a beginner and hardly know anything so please do make it simple

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
      .main{
        background color: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post what you are trying to solve , your question doesn't has enough information for a person to answer it

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is `background-color: yellow;` no `background color: yellow;`

You missed the `-` between `background` and `color`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style media="screen">
      .main{
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">this is test</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues

- Your background color definition is wrong. You should use `background-color` instead of `background color`.
- In order for the div to get displayd inside the dom, you should have some content inside the div or you should define the dimension (width and height) of the div.

  ```css
  .main-1 {
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  .main-2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="main-1">
    You need to have some contents inside the div,
    or you should have defined the dimension of the div
    just as below
  </div>
  <div class="main-2"></div>
  ```